# Using android library project, with multiple src / res folders?

Tags: android, eclipse, library-project

Sorry for what is probably a rather basic question, but I can't find the answer...

I downloaded a project from github, and I'm having trouble setting it up.  I have virtually nill experience using code repositories.  The project is is flagged as an android library project, and has two sets of source folders and resource folders buried in sub directories.  Each src folder is dependent on its own resource folder.

You can see the project layout in the pic below.

Android gives me error that there are no "src" or "res" folders in the main directory.  I tried using "build path > use as source folder" options to make android recognize them, but this leads to errors about not being able to find the resource folders.

How am I suppose to set this up?

[image: project layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used that library before. the problem you are facing is due to wrongly importing the whole repository as 1 project.

it is actually 2 separate projects:

1. `two-way-gridview`. this is the library project. you should import this subfolder on its' own.
2. `sample`. this is a sample project with examples how to use two-way-grid correctly.

you need to import both separately for it to work.

Comment: Thank you...your answer helped me find my root mistake. It was importing it under "General...Existing projects into workspace"  That option would not recognize the subprojects there, even though that's what they appeared to be.  So I looked a little harder, and used the option import "Existing Android Code into Workplace" which saw three projects there. (the top level and 2 sub level projects).